# Prompts are restricting the query result in business object webi rich client?

Tags: business-objects

I'm working on a report in which business layer objects were derived from columns of two tables (Say `A` and `B`).

`Table B` is left outer joined with the `Table A`. I have created a prompt on one of the columns of `Table B`. Now, when I run the query in Web intelligence rich client, the prompt is getting added to the where condition of the query and suppressing the records which are available in `Table A` but not in `Table B`. Please find below sample query that was available in the query script.

```
Select
A.column1,
B.column2
sum(b.measure)
from TABLE_A LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B ON TABLE_A.ID=TABLE_B.ID
where B.column2=@Prompt()
```

I want to present all the records from `Table A` irrespective of data from `Table B`. Is there any way to achieve it. I'm using BusinessObjects 4.0, Information Design Tool and web intelligence rich client for report generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SQL to do what you want would be:

```
select
    A.column1,
    B.column2
    sum(b.measure)
from 
    TABLE_A 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TABLE_B 
        ON TABLE_A.ID=TABLE_B.ID
           AND B.column2=@Prompt()
```

Unfortunately, there's currently no support for dynamically putting an @Prompt() in the FROM clause of a query, short of creating a derived table or fudging the join between A and B.

If this is a one-off need, you could just modify the SQL in the report, but that's not a durable solution.

Depending on the complexity of the actual query and the volume of data in the tables, you could achieve the desired result with multiple queries.  Create one query that includes `ID` and `COLUMN1` from TABLE_A, and another query with `ID`, `COLUMN2`, and `MEASURE` from TABLE_B.  The second query would include the @Prompt() on `COLUMN2`.

In the report, merge the two queries on `ID`.  You may have to create new variables for `COLUMN1` and `COLUMN2` as attributes of the respective `ID` object, but when done the result should be what you want.